# How to recreate this metallic look? (Chrome coating)

Tags: lighting

I'm starting out with Blender and I want to create a similar shape to this one, but I can't seem to find any tutorial good enough to recreate the look.

[image]

How to set up the lighting?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you talking about the shape or about the material? Material seems to be pure metallic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Talking about the material. Like now it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/fooSs2L

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion it's all a question of lighting and HDRI, as it will be what's reflected by your metallic material. Here the material is very basic, just put the *Metallic* value at 1 and lower down the *Roughness*, and choose a studio image for your world (here it comes from polyhaven.com). You can also add some area lights:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for! Thank you very much and sorry for the ambiguous question.